# Movement in Unity is lagging every few seconds and movement looks jumpy

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a game in Unity where an apples falling from top to bottom. The problem is that they don't fall smoothly. In every seconds they move crappy like this:

down, down, down, UP, down, down, down ,UP, down, down, down...

Looks like in every few seconds object jumps up and then falling like it should do and then again jumps up...

The code is very simple:

```
function Update () {
    transform.position.y -= speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

I tried turning off VSync, tried FixedUpdate(with Time.fixedDeltaTime), LateUpdate, Time.smoothDeltaTime, transform.Translate, MoveTowards, Vector3.Lerp, turning on Interpolate of RigidBody, tried even change Time settings and nothing helps even when add a Plane in New Scene and attach this script to Plane.

**Before a moment I tried to attach rigidbody2D to Quad and see what will happens and there is still lag when Quad is falling down even without any code. This makes me wondering why this is happening?**

Comment: Why not use rigidbody to control the gravity effects? Or even use the rigidbody.velocity to change position? If you do use them then make sure they are in the FixedUpdate method

Comment: Before a moment i tried to attach rigidbody2D to Quad and see what will happens and there is still lag when Quad is falling down even without any code. This makes me wondering why this is happening?

Comment: Can you post a video of it? I've tried to recreate the up down falling movement but i can't... Is your unity up to date?

Comment: Print your Time.deltaTime from within the Update() function and look at the values. In a game of mine, I have the strange case that the delta time is much higher in periodic intervals than in the other frames - like so: 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.06, 0.02, 0.02,... This happens only in the Editor, not when I deploy the game to a device.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Time.smoothDeltaTime](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-smoothDeltaTime.html).